# UWP and Get from API fails

Tags: uwp

I have an UWP application and I want to get data from an API.

Build 10586 (I also created a new Build 19041).

I tested the API on a console app and it works fine.

I get the token from an OAUTH, and get the data (on console app),
but when I tried from UWP, sometimes it works on the build 19041 and sometimes it does not).
On the build 10586, it does not work at all.
I want to make it work on the build 10586.

On the mentioned, I do a Microsoft login first from my Azure AAD, I do some graph calls to fetch my 0365 account (which works fine), but calling my API gives the error:

> {"The text associated with this error code could not be found.\r\n\r\nThe connection with the server was reset\r\n"}

My code:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.Security.Cryptography.Certificates;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.Web.Http;
using Windows.Web.Http.Filters;
using Windows.Web.Http.Headers;

private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    var token = await GetToken();
    try
    {
        
        var Email = "testacc.acc.com";
        Uri urlAuth = new Uri(string.Format("https://mylink?email={0}", Email));
        var requestFilter = new HttpBaseProtocolFilter();
        requestFilter.IgnorableServerCertificateErrors.Add(ChainValidationResult.Untrusted);
        using (HttpClient requestClient = new HttpClient(requestFilter))
        {
            var headers = requestClient.DefaultRequestHeaders;
            headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
            requestClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new HttpMediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            var maxRetryCount = 3;
            for (int retry = 0; retry < maxRetryCount; retry++)
            {
                var userListresponse = await requestClient.GetAsync(urlAuth);
                if (userListresponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    // Reading Response.  
                    string jsonResponse = await userListresponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    var valueResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonResponse);
                }
                await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
            }
        }

        

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //
    }
```

The token value is good, tested it on Postman or a console app.

Comment: In Capabilities, Enterprise Auth, Internet(Client and Server), Internet, Private Networks, Shared UserCertificates, User AccountInformation have been checked

Comment: "On the build 10586, it does not work at all", is there any exception throw?